# On the bondary conditions for Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives

Taylor's remainder theorem reads something like this:

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be $k+1$ times differentiable on $(a,b)$, with $f^{(i)}$ continuous on $[a,b]$ for $0\leq i\leq k$. Let $x,c\in[a,b]$ with $x\neq c$. Then there exists $\xi$ between $x$ and $c$ such that

$$R_k(x)=\frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi)}{(k+1)!}(x-c)^{k+1},$$

where $R_k(x)=f(x)-P_k(x)$ is the remainder after subtracting the $k$th Taylor polynomial around the point $c$.

I have two questions:

1. On the Wikipedia page and in Rudin's book the statement of the theorem only assumes $f^{(k)}$ continuous on $[a,b]$. However, looking at the proof, it seems that we need continuity at $a,b$ of all derivatives up to order $k$.
2. If we take an open interval $(a,b)$ instead of $[a,b]$, it seems that the only condition required for Taylor's theorem is $k+1$ differentiability on $(a,b)$. Is this correct?

EDIT: For 1 I think we may use the following reasoning: $f^{(k)}$ continuous on $[a,b]$ implies in particular that $f^{(k)}(a)$ and $f^{(k)}(b)$ are defined. This means that $f^{(k-1)}$ is defined at $a,b$ and differentiable at $a,b$. In particular $f^{(k-1)}$ is continuous at $a,b$, and hence on $[a,b]$. Continuing inductively we get $f^({i})$ continuous on $[a,b]$ for all $0\leq i\leq k$.

Comment: If $f^{(k)}$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ then $f^{(k-1)}$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ and then $f^{(k-2)}$ is continuous on $[a,b],\dots$

Comment: @zhw Ok I see.  So it is slightly weaker than $f$ being $k+1$ times differentiable on $[a,b]$? And what about my second point?